# Superagent moves response callback position in async waterfall

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, node-async, superagent

I have a simple working `superagent`/`async` waterfall request that looks like this:

```
  request = require 'superagent'
  user = request.agent()
  async.waterfall [
    (cb)->
      user.post('http://localhost:3000/form').send(name: 'Bob').end(cb)
  ], (err, res)->
    console.log err
    console.log res
```

This successfully prints my full http response, and `err` is `undefined`.

If I perform the exact same thing with an extra step:

```
  request = require 'superagent'
  user = request.agent()
  async.waterfall [
    (cb)->
      user.post('http://localhost:3000/form').send(name: 'Bob').end(cb)
    (err, res)->
      # this is never reached
      cb()
  ], (err, res)->
    console.log err # this now prints out the response
    console.log res # this is undefined
```

`err` is now the response. `res` is undefined. Is this a `superagent` issue I'm running into here, or am I simply using `async`'s `waterfall` incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a SuperAgent "issue" in how they've chosen to handle the function that is passed as the callback. If that function is expecting exactly two arguments as reported by the [length property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length), then the "traditional" `err` and `res` are given like Async would like. If the function you pass does not report its length to be two, then the first argument given is `res`. Here's [SuperAgent's source for handling callbacks](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/lib/client.js#L780-L785):

```
Request.prototype.callback = function(err, res){
  var fn = this._callback;
  if (2 == fn.length) return fn(err, res);
  if (err) return this.emit('error', err);
  fn(res);
};
```

To guarantee that your callbacks are invoked as intended, I would suggest passing an anonymous function to `end` so that it definitely reports its length as two so you can get any errors passed to your callback.

```
request = require 'superagent'
user = request.agent()
async.waterfall [
  (cb) ->
    user.post('http://localhost:3000/form').send(name: 'Bob').end (err, res) ->
      cb err, res
  (err, res) ->
    # err should be undefined if the request is successful
    # res should be the response
    cb null, res
], (err, res) ->
  console.log err # this should now be null
  console.log res # this should now be the response
```

Answer (score 1):

Async waterfall passes error directly to it's callback. The second function in array receives only one argument - `res`. And every function in array should have it's own callback as the last argument. If error happens you should catch in in waterfall's callback. Try:

```
async.waterfall([
  function(cb){
    superagent...end(cb);
  },
  function(res, cb){ //Note cb here.
    //If you don't pass res here, waterfall's callback will not receive it
    cb(null, res); 
  }], function(err, res){
    //If superagent fails you should catch err here
    should.not.exist(err);
    //res is defined because you passed it to callback of the second function
    should.exist(res); 
 });
```

Comment: I really wanted to accept this answer but unfortunately it isn't working for me. What happens when I run this is that the second function in the array still gets skipped and the response is thrown as `err` in the callback. I guess the real mystery is...why is `superagent` throwing the response?

Comment: Yes, it's very strange. Try to pass `.end()` with a function that manually passes `err` and `res` to the callback. Hope that helps.